# Dompdf image does not render on second page

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

I use DOMPDF for laravel. Why does the image render only on the first page?
On first page you can see the image, on other pages it's just a white box

```html
<style>
* {
  font-family: times;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
 }
 div.breakNow {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-after: always;
 }
 </style>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: DDF9440B15F6287</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: 1925455A7E8DF36</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: 068C168D5B4A076</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: 657FD979CB889CC</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: EEA674085288E6C</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <div class="breakNow"></div>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: 62C2C17DE6D7956</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: 4D156F3F00986EC</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: 577BEC6900D05FA</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: AEB1D9C27F93B39</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: 0E02010791FF539</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <div class="breakNow"></div>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: 98405C583D9D74E</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: DEF3FC6B40F559E</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: ACA8ED32812F15C</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: 28B8BD12A56DEA9</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: E8C93999919A727</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <div class="breakNow"></div>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: 0140CCC5F22F506</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <table style="height: 142px; width: 784.967px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px">
   <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 400px; height: 48px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 48px;"><p>First test Concert</p>
   <p><strong>01/01/1970</strong></p>
   <p>15 $.</p>
   <p>VIP</p></td>
    <td style="width: 188.967px; height: 67px;" rowspan="2" align="center"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://photos.nbeads.com/1/3/6/146_146_136304D9-CE0A-4943-AA68-4DC1140F10EB.JPG" alt="" width="140" height="140" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
    <td style="width: 580px; height: 25px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>&nbsp;code: F4CAA74AD166221</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO2lQ.png)

Comment: Fixed : (display:block) its problem, just delete IT

Comment: It's true, Dompdf does not really like when you mess with the display styling on images ([ref](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/693)).